# How to use distributed user transaction instead of multiple last resources have been added to the current transaction

Tags: java, jboss, transactions

I have a `war` service with three my custom `jar` inside. Every my `jar` use a self-datasource. So, I have three different datasources defined in my JBoss configuration and corresponding persistence.xml where I relate on them. I can depict it as follow:
[image]
Where we have three services: SM, RE and RA and each one have own-datasource. SM and RE use datasources to read and write, but RA just read from DB. The order of these interactions with datasources is presented as numbers near arrows on the picture. So, initially SM reads from DB, and in the end, RE writes to DB.

My question is: what I need to use if I want to write data in the end to both datasources but in one transaction?

There are two possible answers, but both don't satisfy me:

1. Use `UserTransaction` from JBoss in both SM and RE, when I want to write data, and manually handle the begin of a transaction and then commit. But here I have too many additional issues like `WFTXN0001: A transaction is already in progress`, even if I never begin it before. I can't understand how it works, and I can't find concise and clear documentation or example where `UserTransaction` usage is clarified. So, the first answer is "it is too difficult to use, so let's use something else".
2. Reject distributed transaction at all and commit changes to both databases sequentially. I know that it is a trap, but it works if I avoid any transactions using and then insert to WildFly configuration the next property:

```xml
<system-properties>
    <property name="com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.allowMultipleLastResources" value="true"/>
</system-properties>
```

It works! Howerer there is a warning message in the log:

```
16:09:23,581 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (default task-1) ARJUNA012141: Multiple last resources have been added to the current transaction. This is transactionally unsafe and should not be relied upon. Current resource is LastResourceRecord(XAOnePhaseResource(LocalXAResourceImpl@dbaabf3[connectionListener=767c209 connectionManager=78f5d4e2 warned=false currentXid=< formatId=131077, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=36, tx_uid=0:ffff0ac03a90:74af3477:5c7fb46c:343, node_name=1, branch_uid=0:ffff0ac03a90:74af3477:5c7fb46c:35f, subordinatenodename=null, eis_name=java:/db3 > productName=PostgreSQL productVersion=9.6.2 jndiName=java:/db3]))
...
16:09:23,631 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (default task-1) ARJUNA012141: Multiple last resources have been added to the current transaction. This is transactionally unsafe and should not be relied upon. Current resource is LastResourceRecord(XAOnePhaseResource(LocalXAResourceImpl@57a1383c[connectionListener=5ddce49c connectionManager=c66a93f warned=false currentXid=null productName=PostgreSQL productVersion=9.6.9 jndiName=java:/db2]))
```

I want to run away from these terrible messages, but I can't because JBoss restrict me. Maybe you know any other way how to use distributed transaction on JBoss without a pain?

Thanks.

P.S. I don't use Spring. I'm forbidden to use it.

Comment: When I'm working not with Java in the same, but a bit complicated case, where I need to get a transaction for the change of some distributed entity, in the begin of processing I just create a lock on a database and in the end just release it. Such a solution is simple and understandable and has not some implicit interactions between system components. But in Java, I before must understand a monster and then live with him...

Answer (score 0):

Well, not using Spring is not such a bad thing.

Your diagram has a WAR file that accesses three databases via the various jars.  What persistence service (if any) are you using?

What is your transaction demarcation?  You should be making the database calls in the same transaction context.  You should not need to start a user transaction.  If you use the '@Transactional' annotation on your web service class, JBoss will start a transaction and the database accesses should be joining the transaction.

Comment: The hibernate is used in every `jar`. And yes, you're right, all three datasources are defined in persistence.xml of the `war`.
I'll try to annotate with `@Transactional` all methods where I write to DB (calls 4 and 5 on my diagram). But is it need to mark the classes with those methods? Note, my writer classes can be not `@EJB` but have a link to `EntityManager` inited from `@EJB`.

Comment: I checked `@Transactional` and it does not work. I'll try to switch off EJB transaction on the entry EJB method with `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.???)` and then use `UserTransaction` manually, and hope that it will not be activated.

Comment: No. I tried to use `TransactionAttributeType.NEVER or TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED` for the entry EJB method, and use an instance of `UserTransaction` with manually `.begin()`, `.commit()` and `.rollback()`, but got the same error that a transaction is already in progress in the point of the first `.begin()` call.
I also tried to use another (short) scenario of my system, where isn't 4 call (according to my diagram). So, I have the same error with already activated transaction even in such short scenario case.